# C - Read .doc file as 32 bit binary numbers

Tags: c, binary, file-handling

It's just a practice task , as "Every file is just a binary file with different set of bytes." , i am reading a `.doc` file as binary file, let suppose

"this .doc file is actually a binary file with 32-bit unsigned numbers and i want to sort them as ascending within the file."

Now so far my logic is to count total bytes from file divide them by `sizeof(int)` , and make `int` array of that size. and start reading bytes . but there is a problem in this logic : 
**file.doc**  with size `250 bytes` where `sizeof(int)` = 4 , now `250/4 = 62.5` , i made an array of 63 integers , now how will i handle `63rd integer` , as 32 bit binary number ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like `rem = filesize % sizeof(int)` to get the number of bytes after the last contiguous block of `sizeof(int)` bytes, and for the last integer in the array do `fread(&array[i], rem, 1, stream)`.

Comment: i didn't get your logic , any chunk would be appreciated.

Comment: In C, division of integers yields the whole number quotient without the remainder, so 250/4 = 62. '%', the modulus operator, yields the remainder of one number divided by another, so 250 % 4 = 2. You want to view the file as a block of 4-byte blocks, since an integer is 4 bytes in size. Since the file is only 250 bytes in size, 250/4 = 62 gives you the number of whole integers you can read from the file, while 250 % 4 gives you the number of bytes left over, which is 2 bytes. So you can just read 2 bytes into the last integer. Just substitute 4 for 'sizeof(int)' and 250 for 'filesize'.

Comment: 250 as filesize was just assumption , but it is very good way to achieve the task, reading the last bytes , but you know they are 2 bytes in this case but bytes can be 3 or 1 also ! , for 2 bytes i can easily using `short` for the last special case what about in case of 3 or 1 bytes ?

Comment: You can just read the bytes into the lower order bytes of a 4-byte integer. It will have the same result as reading them into a short or a char, as it will hold the same numeric value. Many functions, such as fgetc, isalpha, isdigit, etc. treat integers as one-byte chars, because it is the numeric value that matters. I would just stick with one type, as you would have an odd variable outside of the array, which would hinder any efforts to treat the contents of the file as a contiguous array.

Answer (score 0):

Usually these problems are handled by adding padding. You can pretend that the original file has been filled with zeros (for example) until the next multiple of 4 bytes.

Comment: padding , the leftover memory which is needed to cover up bytes mechanism right? how can it help in such case ?

Comment: You are asking how to handle the last number, given that you only have 2 bytes for it. Pretending that there are two more bytes is the solution. That is, you "pad" the file to the next multiple of four.